# iOS Deezer App remote control from other app?

Tags: ios, deezer

Is there a way to remote control iOS deezer app from another iOS app via deep linking and [x-callback](http://x-callback-url.com) ? If no, any plan in the future ?

Comment: You will need to ask the Deezer developers this.